# Ionic-3 Photo-library plugin crashes in iOS version 13. Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file

Tags: crash, ionic3, cordova-plugins, ios13, photolibrary

Ionic-3 Photo-library plugin crashes in iOS version 13. Works fine in iOS 12 version.

Here is the log:

2019-09-30 12:03:03.878478+0530 destinate[453:135517] [core] "Error returned from daemon: Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 “(null)”"

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Volumes/Data/Projects/Destinate/destinate/platforms/ios/destinate/Plugins/cordova-plugin-photo-library/PhotoLibraryService.swift, line 314

2019-09-30 12:03:04.117471+0530 destinate[453:134941] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file /Volumes/Data/Projects/Destinate/destinate/platforms/ios/destinate/Plugins/cordova-plugin-photo-library/PhotoLibraryService.swift, line 314

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue?