# Photo-library plugin crash in ios version 13

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, uiimagepickercontroller

[Reposted: question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165076/ionic-3-photo-library-plugin-crashes-in-ios-version-13-unexpectedly-found-nil-w)

app crashes when the user wants to fetch images from the library in ionic 3.

[image picker plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/image-picker/) works fine in iOS 12. But after updating to iOS 13, it is crashing.

it is working in iPhone X but when trying it on iPad it's getting the error which is in the link given above.

can anyone help with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add property in ImagePicker options:

```
disable_popover: true
```

It will solve the crashing issue.But the error still would be there in logs!
Happy coding!!!

Comment: Solved it using this.

Comment: That didn't solve the problem for me, any other ideas? Xcode 11, ios 13